# [Ruby]: Perform variety of operations on a text document

Tags: ruby

I am a beginner. I am making a text editor wherein a user can perform variety of operations and can even convert it to a rich text.

Here are my queries:

(1) I want to provide the user a text-editing window wherein they can type-in text. How to do this? Which control and what-so-ever is involved?

(2) When the user has entered text, how to perform operations on the text. Do I need to take it in a buffer or something better? A user can select a portion of text and my program must determine that portion and perform operations on it.

Comment: Are you aiming to make a Rails site that does this or a standalone app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're going to need a GUI
   framework. Several are listed in
   [this SO
   question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260905).
   Don't jump straight for shoes,
   however: it may not have all the
   capabilities you need for your
   second question. Shoes is an
   excellent lightweight framework but
   you're probably going to need to go
   deeper.
2. Take a good long look at the
   [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html)
   class, you're going to need it.
   You're also going to need to respond
   to events within the text box
   control of whatever framework you
   choose, so check that it's able to
   tell you about things like
   key-down/up,
   mouse-down/up/click/drag and so on.