# Ruby as a standalone language

Tags: ruby, desktop-application

I have been messing around with ruby on rails. But my questions is really simple. Is ruby used language used for desktop applications? I mean without Rails? Can it be combined with GUI packages and Graphics Libraries to create a game for example? I have read that ruby is based on C. So it will be fast right?

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Please try to ask one question per question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260905/whats-the-best-easiest-gui-library-for-ruby

Comment: Ruby is a great language, but not as fast as you'd expect for gaming considering it's interpreted.

Comment: I have heard computers are based on electricity. Electricity is fast. Therefore, all computers are fast. See the fallacy? The question is, is Ruby *fast enough*? And, in many cases, it is. It doesn't matter what language it [Ruby] was written in (actually, [JRuby](http://jruby.org/), Ruby written in Java, [is faster that the C MRI in cases](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php)).

Comment: See [With what tools can I make a complex and advanced GUI with Ruby?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/53553/36725).

Answer (score 16):

> Is ruby used language used for desktop applications?

Yes it is.

> I mean without Rails?

Yes.

> Can it be combined with GUI packages and Graphics Libraries to create a game for example?

Yes it can be.

> I have read that ruby is based on C. So it will be fast right?

No, it won't be "fast" in the same way C is fast, because that isn't the point of Ruby. Ruby isn't "based on" C in any sense. The interpreter which runs Ruby code *may* be written in C (there are many interpreters and not all of them are), but that has nothing to do with the language itself. C and Ruby are not really comparable and occupy *completely* different niches.

Comment: I wish I could vote twice for this

Comment: Ruby is generally not "C fast" when number crunching, etc. However, when coupled with a relatively slow user (most of the time computers wait on *us* ;-), it can very well be "fast enough".

Comment: Actually, the Rubinius `Hash` class, which is written in Ruby is faster than the YARV `Hash` class which is written in C. So, this is at least one example where Ruby is *faster* than C.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The fact that you have to prove that there is *at least* one example kind of proves our point.

Answer (score 3):

I've no experience in programs where speed is critical; however, from my experience, Ruby is fast enough for user applications with GUI, and differences are almost unnoticeable from other similar dynamical languages (Ruby 1.9 is even faster, sometimes).

There is a reason I don't name the "similar languages": I think languages benchmarks aren't useful at all. While the fact that Ruby is fast enough for general purpose programming will probably make you happy, I think it's more important that if you already know and like Ruby you will be more productive using it.

There are some limit cases Ruby will be even faster than C: your implementations in C for functions that are offered as methods in the Ruby core lang and std lib could be slower than the ones in Ruby VM. This is just to say, speed isn't usually a concern, unless you're actually well aware of a particular reason you should be concerned with speed.

Some nice GUI libraries are [FXRuby](http://www.fxruby.org/) and [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/), a very easy library used in the [Hackety Hack](http://hackety.com/) project to teach children to program.
I usually use [Tk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tk/rdoc/index.html) when programming with Ruby and Python because it's included in the standard library and there is no need to install anything else.

For Gaming, you can try [Gosu](http://www.libgosu.org/) and [Chingu](http://ippa.se/chingu); Gosu is probably the most actively developed Ruby Gaming Library, and Chingu is a nice collection of classes based on the foundations offered by Gosu. They've not got the nice community of other gaming libraries (e.g. Pygame) but you can easily start making little games with them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Shoes GUI, it has different implementations, each one has a colorname, the most popular ared Red and Green Shoes, they are often used to make the kind of games you see also in Flash or regular javascript. They are fast enough for that kind of games. Some implementations even work with JRuby.

- [Red Shoes](http://shoes.heroku.com/)
- [Green Shows](https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes)

Comment: You can also check out visualruby:  visualruby.net

Comment: @user1182000, seems nice, found a download at http://visualruby.net/site/Download.html

Comment: ..but it's only the Gui-interface (Glade), no trace of the Visual Ruby IDE, any idea if this is avaiable for Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) is a language whose common implementation (e.g. [ruby-1.9.3-pl94](http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.gz)) is an interpreter coded in C. File `main.c` contains the `main` function in C which set up the Ruby VM implemented in C in file `vm.c`.

You could have several implementations of Ruby. I heard that some people wanted to re-implement Ruby above the [Parrot VM](http://www.parrot.org/) (itself implemented in C); but that effort is perhaps still in progress. [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) is a Ruby above the JVM.

Indeed interpreter vs compiler is not a sharp difference. Many interpreters contain a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) with a translator (which you could view as a compiler) to that VM. Some VM implementations have a [Just In Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) dynamic translator to machine code. The JIT part produces machine code dynamically.

You could code a graphical application using e.g. [Ruby-Gnome](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/), a glue to Gnome and Gtk. You could also use [Ruby Qt](http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum/), a glue to KDE and Qt

Comment: -1 for so many reasons. First off, there is no such thing as an interpreted language (and even if there were, then Ruby wouldn't be one, since almost every single Ruby implementation has a compiler). Secondly, there is no such thing as "its implementation", there many implementations. And thirdly, the vast majority of Ruby implementations are not written in C.

Comment: "Maybe some people tried a Ruby above JVM thing." Nice FUD. [Do or do not. There is no try](http://jruby.org/).

Comment: Corrected with your link