# Inputbox() function in vbs

Tags: vbscript

I am using `InputBox()` function in my vbscript code and it's working fine and I am using various of `InputBox()` functions.

Now my question is every time when `InputBox()` is called, it opens in a separate window. Is there any way or function that I can input my data only in one window page and all inputs are handle with one submit button?

Comment: Its time to shift from vbs to VB!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ perilbrain, VB.NET is no scripting language, neither was VB which is as dead as VBscript, Ruby is a very good replacement for me

Answer (score 2):

You can't re-use the 'same' InputBox, but for a few simple inputs you could ask once for several items and parse the user's input (like command line arguments). In the long run - and for many inputs - it's better to use an HTA Application.

P.S. (wrt to peter's proposal)

> HTAs are full-fledged applications. These applications are trusted and
>   display only the menus, icons, toolbars, and title information that
>   the web developer creates. In short, HTAs pack all the power of
>   Internet Explorer—its object model, performance, rendering power and
>   protocol support—without enforcing the strict security model and user
>   interface of the browser.

([MS on HTAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

[Tutorial to get you started](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A part from using a HTA you can use Internet Explorer like a GUI and use all the goodies of HTML to interact between your script an the user. See this question of me with a vbscript sample.

[use-browser-as-gui-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724201/use-browser-as-gui-in-ruby)

see also my answer here [/adding-a-gui-to-vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052534/adding-a-gui-to-vbscript/16054011#16054011)