# Portable Ruby GUI Toolkit

Tags: ruby, user-interface, toolkit

I am in need of a GUI toolkit that goes a little further than tk does, but my school's computers do not allow programs to run if they try to create/alter files on the local disk.  Because of that, I need a portable GUI toolkit for Windows.  Does anybody know of one?

Comment: I know that the [Qt4 library](http://qt.digia.com/try-qt-now/) includes Ruby language bindings; it might work in-memory only... ?

Comment: Heh.  Teenager who spends most of his time programming = broke teenager, who cant afford anything but free when it comes to software XD

Comment: that's how I cut my teeth, it did me good! =)

Comment: through some psuedo-random clicking, I got to this site: http://qt-project.org    However, I do not want to download 1.7gb onto my flashdrive without asserting that it will work and is portable.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: What does "further" mean to you? More widgets? More modern look? Stylesheets? Printing support? HTML support? Since you are just learning, you might be surprised at just how far Tk can take you. Though, if you're looking for something specific please let us know so we can give relevant suggestions.

Comment: I am creating a simple fractal program, but I want a few more features than what Tk is giving me, nothing in particular, but just more power, you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green Shoes, just install the gem, copy it along with your Ruby map to a stick and you are off to go.

```
gem install green_shoes
```

http://ashbb.github.com/green_shoes/App.html

a simple sample

```
require 'green_shoes'
Shoes.app{
  e = edit_line
  button("Click me!"){alert("You entered #{e.text}")}
}
```

Comment: Heh, well, Green Shoes itself seems to be portable..  But it requires gtk2.... Which isnt portable as far as I can tell....  As someone on irc put it: I am like a prisoner in a cage -_-  oh well, I will eventually get it to work ^^

Comment: i use green shoes on windows vista pc's where nothing of Ruby nor gtk2 is installed, they execute the script by loading everything from network, it is slow but it works

Answer (score 1):

Qt4 and ruby-qt (the qtbindings gem works beautifully to get the ruby bindings)

Comment: see http://blog.shoesrb.com/post/1480014928/other-ruby-gui-toolkits-qtruby for a comparison between qtruby and shoes, i let you decide who wins

Comment: and an absolutely not biased comparison ;-). Btw, one thing you get with qt: Qt Designer to draw your forms / windows graphically.

Comment: The URL given for the comparison is dead but the post can be found at archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/http://blog.shoesrb.com/post/1480014928/other-ruby-gui-toolkits-qtruby

Answer (score 0):

For graphical applications in Ruby, I personally prefer JRuby + Swing. Presumably your school's computers have a JRE installed... perhaps you can run JRuby from your flash drive?

Comment: Maybe, I will try tomorrow ^^

Comment: if you use jRuby, take also a look at Purple Shoes

Answer (score 0):

I see you haven't yet accepted an answer, so i try another suggestion.
Again, you only need a Gem, Watir in this case. 
Your browser is the GUI.
Here a question i asked and the answer i accepted

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724201/use-browser-as-gui-in-ruby
```

That example uses IE but the other browsers are possible too, this solution is cross-browser and cross OS

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the time to check it, school got really busy ^^