# Retrieve data that has been entered on a page to a program

Tags: html, css, ruby, web-applications

I want to retrieve information from a form I have created using HTML and CSS to my Ruby program and apply some operation and redirect to another page accordingly. Since I am a beginner so I don't have much knowledge about web development so if please anyone could help!!!

Comment: You're not gonna get any help if you don't post any code. What do you have so far?

Comment: Are you using any web framework like Rails, Sinatra, Hanami, ?

Comment: No I am not using any of the frame work

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing what you want, if not correct please provide more info and the meanigfull parts of what you tried in code.

Take a look at the accepted answer for my question at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724201/use-browser-as-gui-in-ruby](http://use-browser-as-gui-in-ruby)

Here part of what  [Justin Ko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1200545/justin-ko) answered

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::IE.new
begin
    b.goto('file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Setup/Desktop/test.htm')
    begin
        sleep(5)
    end until b.button(:id, 'submit').value != "OK"
    name = b.text_field.value
ensure
    b.close
end
puts name
```