# Can you create inputbox with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have used VBScript in the past for QTP and I could use the input box function to display a pop up window.

I am wondering if there is a way to do this with Ruby? I need a popup that will allow the user to input some information before the WATIR script executes.

I looked around StackOverflow but didn't see anything.

Comment: by ruby, do you mean using ruby on rails, or some other ruby web framework?

Comment: Double that question. You just want quick UI framework for dektop apps in ruby?

Comment: I've heard that shoes (http://shoesrb.com/) is good for Ruby frontends, but I've never used it.

Answer (score 3):

Here an example of how to get the messagebox from vbscript in Ruby, i'll try to get the inputbox in the same way

```
require "Win32API"  

message = "This is a sample Windows message box generated using Win32API"  
title = "Win32API from Ruby"  

api = Win32API.new('user32','MessageBox',['L', 'P', 'P', 'L'],'I')  
api.call(0,message,title,0)
```

Comment: Cool.  Its not for ruby on rails and can it be done for a Mac/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example code helps you (win32 only):

```
require 'win32ole'

def inputbox( message, title="Message from #{__FILE__}" )
  vb_msg = %Q| "#{message.gsub("\n",'"& vbcrlf &"')}"|
  vb_msg.gsub!( "\t", '"& vbtab &"' )
  vb_msg.gsub!( '&""&','&' )
  vb_title = %Q|"#{title}"|
  # go!
  sc = WIN32OLE.new( "ScriptControl" )
  sc.language = "VBScript"
  sc.eval(%Q|Inputbox(#{vb_msg}, #{vb_title})|)
  #~ sc.eval(%Q|Inputbox(#{vb_msg}, #{vb_title}, aa,hide)|)
end
def popup(message)
  wsh = WIN32OLE.new('WScript.Shell')
  wsh.popup(message, 0, __FILE__)
end


str = "a |  does not break it...\n\nOne\n\tTwo tabbed\nThree..."
res = inputbox( str, "demonstration | title")
popup %Q|When asked\n\n"#{str}"\n\nyou answered:\n#{res}|
```

This results in:

[image: Inputbox]

It follows a popup box with.

See also http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/04/ruby-excel-inputbox-hack.html

Answer (score 1):

Since i can't find an inputbox api for windows here is what i do most of the time if i need some simple dialog. Unlike red shoes it is just a gem so easy to install.

```
require 'green_shoes'
Shoes.app{
  e = edit_line
  button("Click me!"){alert("You entered." + e.text)}
}
```

Comment: @ Peter                                                                     I tried installing GreenShoes but got this error message:      Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing green_shoes:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  
        /Users/joe.fleck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb                                                                      Is it because I am running with ruby-1.8.7?   Thank you.

Comment: could be, i use ruby-1.9.3-p194 on windows and had no trouble at all, i even use it on windows pc's with no Ruby installed, just running ruby from a network share

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is a programing/scripting language, so on it's own it doesn't do any kind of GUI or Graphics related stuff. That being said there are quite a few projects and frameworks that use Ruby to accomplish the type of thing you are looking for. The big ones are [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) that uses Ruby to create web applications, and [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) which is for creating computer applications.

There is also this question
[What's the best/easiest GUI Library for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260905/whats-the-best-easiest-gui-library-for-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [shoes](http://shoesrb.com/), it's a cross-platform toolkit for writing graphical apps.

I used it and it's pretty cool, you can do something like:

```
Shoes.app :width => 300, :height => 200 do
  stack do
    edit_line :width => 400
  end
end
```