# How to display a lightweight web client window with ruby

Tags: ruby, webkit, raspberry-pi, archlinux, xorg

I need to display a web page on a PAL 7" monitor with a Raspberry Pi without user controls (no keyboard, no mouse, just display).

The context is :

- Raspberry Pi platform
- 7" PAL LCD monitor
- archlinux ARM
- no desktop environment
- xorg or eventually a minimalistic window manager (openbox, pekwm,etc.)
- Ruby language (1.9.3 or eventually 2.0.0)
- webkit or other web engine but html5 compatible (I want to use websocket)

What is the best way to display a web page in this context ?

Thanks !

Comment: Elaborate. This is not descriptive. Do you want to create a web app and run a Firefox there, or you want to create a Ruby application that has a built-in browser?

Comment: I want to create a Ruby application with built-in browser to simply display a web page from intranet web server

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

[What's the best/easiest GUI Library for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260905/whats-the-best-easiest-gui-library-for-ruby)

The real issue with Ruby is that support of GUI toolkits is really poor. And if you want to use websocket, I don't think there are options right know (maybe Ruby QT with webkit browser - not sure).

Why do you need this application to be coded in Ruby? I'd recommend you to spawn a normal browser like Firefox or Opera in "kiosk" mode (Opera has kiosk mode built-in and Firefox has a plugin for that), so you can code your application as a normal web application and let the Firefox to connect there.