# Is it possible to create native graphical user interfaces in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, wxruby

I am considering using Ruby for a project, but I'm a complete beginner, so don't know what is, or is not, possible with Ruby 2.0.

I have looked at `wxRuby`, but it hasn't been updated since 2009, so I take it that means it is not compatible with RUby 2.0.

Is there another option for creating native GUIs, or are these not done in the Ruby land?

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible and [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) has gained some attention lately.  That said, there are quit a few wrappers around QT and GTK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best/easiest GUI Library for Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260905/whats-the-best-easiest-gui-library-for-ruby)

Comment: See [With what tools can I make a complex and advanced GUI with Ruby?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/53553/36725).

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to create GUIs with Ruby, but it doesn't appear to be widely done. Off the top of my head I can think of the following projects that might help you:

- [rwx](https://rubygems.org/gems/rwx) - project was created as a successor to wxRuby
- [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/) for iOS, Android and OS X

Comment: Why isn't it widely done? I'm more interested in whether people usually make desktop/mobile UIs, rather than whether it's possible as I am currently looking for the right tool for a small "Pomodoro" desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's certainly possible to create GUIs with Ruby. You can see my full list of [Ruby GUI libraries here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/57966/36725).

However, desktop Ruby GUI apps aren't widely developed because the Ruby community is heavily weighted toward web application developers, and they are much more likely to build a web application than a desktop application. Ruby is the language of hip tech startups, and conventional user interfaces don't suit their aesthetic.

Also, it's very difficult to build native-looking cross-platform GUI apps, so web applications tend to be more acceptable to end users.